# Error in getting record Id in Lightning component quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, error, error-messages, quickaction

I am getting the Error:

> Component class instance initialization error 
>   [Cannot read property 'g' of undefined]
>   quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component - forceChatter:lightningComponent

There is not call to Apex method/Chatter used in this program. Kindly, review the code and help. Thanks in advance

**COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" /> 
    <aura:handler name="UpdateOpp" action="{!c.updateOpportunity}" value="{!this}" />

</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    updateOpportunity : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('Executing...' + component.get("v.recordId") );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use force:hasRecordId, do *not* define your own recordId.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="UpdateOpp" action="{!c.updateOpportunity}" value="{!this}" />
</aura:component>
```

UpdateOpp is not a value name for a value handler. The documentation demonstrates a button to click on to do something, but if you're just getting started, you can see how it works by using the name "init":

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.updateOpportunity}" value="{!this}" />
</aura:component>
```

If you wanted a named event UpdateOpp, you would need to register an event:

```
<aura:register name="UpdateOpp" event="force:recordSave" 
    action="{!c.updateOpportunity}" />
```

You would need to select the appropriate event to use for the event attribute.